# Relative path of angular asset folder resulting as 404

Tags: html, angular, regex, apache, apache2

UI : Angular
My image path is like this,

```
src="../../assets/images/xyz.png"
```

and it was working fine when i was dumping all the dist under the apache root --> /var/www/html but now i am having sub-folder wise in apache ie.

```
/var/www/html/abc
```

under this, i dump all the dist items of angular. but now most of my images are getting 404. I can understand that if i change the path of src to this

```
src="./assets/images/xyz.png"
```

it will work, but i have tons of files if to change. Is the htaccess can do any re-write to all my images, json
I already have base href in place as

```
<base href="/abc/">
```

Any help would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

try `src="assets/images/xyz.png"`. assets folder should be transfered to you build folder

Comment: yes that is true but i have lot of files to change, is there any option to do this change in htaccess ?

Comment: make regexp replace `src="[^"]+*(assets/.+)"` to `src="$1"`, I believe that is just the best option

Comment: sorry my bad, can u help me , like where i need to place this command?

Comment: use you IDE replace with regex option

Comment: No, i cannot change the source code, it is managed by other team. I have only option to change all the apache and its config

Comment: try to debug, what paths are being requested, and setup path transformation. but that solution is a bit weird

Comment: yeah i did. it is working if src="assets/images/xyz.png" but it is getting 404 if src="../../"

Comment: the request are going like this, src="../../"

Comment: by this when we click the resource am getting 404, with path showing as src="assets/sys.jpg" instead it should be src="abc/assets/sys.jpg"

Comment: do you know how to use browser devtools network tab?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230480/discussion-between-jithin-kumar-s-and-andrei).